# Break up/parse a URL into its constituent parts in php

Tags: php, url, url-parsing

What is the best way to parse a URL into its corresponding paths, such that

```
https://www.example.com/path/to/directory/file.jpeg?param1=foo&param2=bar
```

Results in an array holding

```
Array(
    ["scheme"] => "https",
    ["host"] => www.example.com
    ["directory"] => "path/to/directory"
    ["filename"] => "file"
    ["extension] => "jpeg"
    ["path"] => "path/to/directory/file.jpeg",
    ["file"] => "file.jpeg"
    ["params"] => Array(
        ["param1"] => "foo",
        ["param2"] => "bar"
    )
)
```

**Note:** The keys do not need to be named like this, they are just an example.

I have looked into parse_url, but it doesn't split up the path  fine grained enough, so further manual processing seems inevitable.

**Sidenote:** I have looked into [very](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218010/how-do-i-break-apart-a-url-to-its-component-parts-in-php) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257243/php-how-to-split-url) [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810577/parse-url-in-php) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102366/regex-for-parsing-url-php) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35207936/150926), but I can't find any definite reference, thus my question.

Comment: Did this "question" really need to be asked? Sounds like a specific need you have so you wrote code to solve it. I don't think there was any real knowledge deficit around this that required this to be posted.

Comment: it is meant to become a reference question/answer I guess. The question's wording is a bit too acurate tbh but the answer is fine.

Comment: @Akintunde, if there is something wrong with the answer, please comment what (and down-vote), accordingly; or better yet, give a better answer yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get parts of URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6985505/608639)

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to combine the efforts of multiple builtin php functions such as [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url) (for the basic url parts), [parse_str](http://php.net/parse_str) (for the query parameters) and [pathinfo](http://php.net/pathinfo) (for the directory, filename and extension parts).

### **parse_url**

parse_url will parse the url and split it up into an associative array containing the following keys (if they are present in the url):

- scheme (http, https, ftp, ...)
- host (www.example.com)
- port
- user
- pass
- path (this will need further processing)
- query (this will need further processing)
- fragment (the anchor/hashbang part, anything after the hash mark)

### **parse_str**

parse_str can be used to parse the `query` part from parse_url into a multidimensional (if needed) associative array.

### pathinfo

pathinfo can be used to parse the `path` part from parse_url into an associative array which can contain the following keys:

```
[dirname] => /path/to/directory
[basename] => file.jpeg
[extension] => jpeg
[filename] => file
```

### Putting it all together

```
function decompose_url($url) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    if (!$parts) {
        # For seriously malformed urls
        return false;
    }
    # Just for good measure, throw in the top level domain, if there is a host with a top level domain
    if (array_key_exists('host', $parts) && strrpos($parts['host'], '.') !== false) {
        $domain_parts = explode('.', $parts['host']);
        $parts['tld'] = end($domain_parts);
    }
    if (array_key_exists('path', $parts)) {
        $pathinfo = pathinfo($parts['path']);
        if (empty($pathinfo['basename'])) {
            # With an empty basename, extension and filename will also be empty
            unset($pathinfo['basename']);
            unset($pathinfo['extension']);
            unset($pathinfo['filename']);

        }
        $parts = array_merge($parts, $pathinfo);
    }
    if (array_key_exists('query', $parts)) {
        parse_str($parts['query'], $query_parts);
        $parts['query_parts'] = $query_parts;
    }
    return $parts;
}
```

### Giving it a test

```
$urls = [
    'http://www.example.com/',
    'http://www.example.com',
    'http://www.example.com/test/.jpg',
    'http://www.example.com/test/.'
    'https://anonymous:dCU7egW1A1L0a6pxU3qu9@www.example.com:8080/path/to/directory/file.jpeg?param1=foo&param2=bar&param3[1]=abc&param3[2]=def#anchor',
    'ftp://anonymous@ftp.example.com/pub/test.jpg',
    'file:///home/user/.config/test.config',
    'chrome://settings/passwords',
];

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    echo $url, PHP_EOL;
    var_export(decompose_url($url));
    echo PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL;
}
```

will yield these corresponding results:

```
http://www.example.com/
array (
  'scheme' => 'http',
  'host' => 'www.example.com',
  'path' => '/',
  'tld' => 'com',
  'dirname' => '/',
)

http://www.example.com
array (
  'scheme' => 'http',
  'host' => 'www.example.com',
  'tld' => 'com',
)

http://www.example.com/test/.jpg
array (
  'scheme' => 'http',
  'host' => 'www.example.com',
  'path' => '/test/.jpg',
  'tld' => 'com',
  'dirname' => '/test',
  'basename' => '.jpg',
  'extension' => 'jpg',
  'filename' => '',
)

http://www.example.com/test/.
array (
  'scheme' => 'http',
  'host' => 'www.example.com',
  'path' => '/test/.',
  'tld' => 'com',
  'dirname' => '/test',
  'basename' => '.',
  'extension' => '',
  'filename' => '',
)

https://anonymous:dCU7egW1A1L0a6pxU3qu9@www.example.com:8080/path/to/directory/file.jpeg?param1=foo&param2=bar&param3[1]=abc&param3[2]=def#anchor
array (
  'scheme' => 'https',
  'host' => 'www.example.com',
  'port' => 8080,
  'user' => 'anonymous',
  'pass' => 'dCU7egW1A1L0a6pxU3qu9',
  'path' => '/path/to/directory/file.jpeg',
  'query' => 'param1=foo&param2=bar&param3[1]=abc&param3[2]=def',
  'fragment' => 'anchor',
  'tld' => 'com',
  'dirname' => '/path/to/directory',
  'basename' => 'file.jpeg',
  'extension' => 'jpeg',
  'filename' => 'file',
  'query_parts' => 
  array (
    'param1' => 'foo',
    'param2' => 'bar',
    'param3' => 
    array (
      1 => 'abc',
      2 => 'def',
    ),
  ),
)

ftp://anonymous@ftp.example.com/pub/test.jpg
array (
  'scheme' => 'ftp',
  'host' => 'ftp.example.com',
  'user' => 'anonymous',
  'path' => '/pub/test.jpg',
  'tld' => 'com',
  'dirname' => '/pub',
  'basename' => 'test.jpg',
  'extension' => 'jpg',
  'filename' => 'test',
)

file:///home/user/.config/test.config
array (
  'scheme' => 'file',
  'path' => '/home/user/.config/test.config',
  'dirname' => '/home/user/.config',
  'basename' => 'test.config',
  'extension' => 'config',
  'filename' => 'test',
)

chrome://settings/passwords
array (
  'scheme' => 'chrome',
  'host' => 'settings',
  'path' => '/passwords',
  'dirname' => '/',
  'basename' => 'passwords',
  'filename' => 'passwords',
)
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need to check if a key exists in an array before unsetting it, so you can do `unset($pathinfo['basename'], $pathinfo['extension'], $pathinfo['filename']);`