# Get filename from URL without path or extension?

Tags: php

My string looks like this:

```
$str = www.example.com/forums/pages/name.php
```

I will like to get this:

```
name
```

I have tried:

```
echo rtrim($str,".php");
```

But I am getting `www.example.com/forums/pages/name`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "I will like to remove the last character from a string, clear the characters before it and return the rest." -> you'll get an empty string :) Can you rephrase that please, and share your attempts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Break up/parse a URL into its constituent parts in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46796837/608639)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using pathinfo()

```
$a_info = pathinfo("www.site.com/forums/pages/name.php");
echo $a_info["filename"];
```

$a_info["filename"] will give you "name"

you can also get other details from pathinfo

```
Array
(
    [dirname] => www.site.com/forums/pages
    [basename] => name.php
    [extension] => php
    [filename] => name
)
```

Answer (score -1):

The substr() function returns a part of a string.

Note: If the start parameter is a negative number and length is less than or equal to start, length becomes 0.

[link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp)

```
echo substr($str,26,29); // this will give output -  name.php
```

EDIT:

```
$str = "www.example.com/forums/pages/name.php";
$start = strrpos($str,"/")+1; // using strrpos to get position of "/"
$length = strrpos($str,".")-$start; // using strrpos to get position of "." and then subtracting start position to get its length
echo substr($str,$start,$length); // this will echo out the name
```

Comment: This is a very volatile answer.

Comment: yes i agree with this

Comment: IMO, in that case you should remove this answer, or improve it.

Comment: @user3783243 check the update to the ans. Is it correct now?

Comment: It is better. I'd still prefer the built function for this. Parsing this way can still give incorrect results. e.g. `my.file.jpg`, `.htaccess`